# Nodejs asynchronous events cause wrong order

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, asynchronous

Let's say I have the following function inside a function:

```
function (arr){
    newArray = [];

    arr.forEach(function(prop){  
        //extract  data from arr into newArray with newArray.push(),
        //this is done through fs and ffmpeg events

    }

console.log(newArray); //empty, because of async problems
//I want to proceed with my code here

}
```

Now as you can see, I am extracting data from an old array into a new array, and each newArray.push is done through an event which involves some packages like fs and FFmpeg, and they are run only when you have nothing on the stack... the problem is, Since the JS core runs synchronously, 
console.log(newArray); is empty, and I can't see all the new values.
I just want to proceed with my code after the for each and it's events are done, not before.

So, how do I solve this problem? async package could be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes async npm will help for this case.

```
async.eachSeries(arr, function(item, callback) {
    fs.writeFile(item, item, function(err) {
    if(!err) {
        newArray.push(item);
    }    
    callback();
    }); 
}, function done() {
    console.log(newArray)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting for your array to be filled , you could use [async each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) method :

```
async.each(arr, function(prop, callback) {

 // your code to proceed with the item 
  // call callback() once you want to move on the next item

}, function(err){
    if( err ) {
  console.log('An item failed to process');
} else {
  // this is where you can play with newArray[] now that it's filled 
  // console.log(newArray) shouldn't show you empty
  console.log('All items have been processed successfully');
}
});
```

Comment: Check the documentation, it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that your `arr.forEach` inner functions fill the `newArray` AFTER you call `console.log(newArray)`.

Beside libraries like `async` or the imho much nicer `co` (uses Promises), you can add a callback manually like this:

```
function (arr){
    newArray = [];
    cnt = arr.length
    arr.forEach(function(prop){
         ...
         cnt--
         if (cnt == 0) { console.log(newArray) }
    }
}
```

With `co` you would maybe use `Array.map` instead of `Array.forEach`and write something like this:

```
newArray = yield arr.map(co.wrap(function*(prop) { ... return elem }))
console.log(newArray)
```